# Floating horizontal bar for html table

Tags: html, css

The columns in my html table are very large in number and I have to scroll all the way to view  these elements.

I tried enclosing the html table within the below div;

```
div.scroll
{
overflow:scroll;
}
```

But the problem is, the scroll bars appear in the bottom of the table and I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the table and again navigate back to the required row and view it.

I want the scroll bars[both horizontal and vertical] to be floating so that I can scroll across starting from the first row and first column.[Similar to this demo: http://www.matts411.com/static/demos/grid/index.html ] .

I dont want to use any third party libraries. Is this possible ?

Comment: Do not put your content inside the table, if you want the scroll effect. because table will take the auto height. put all the content inside a div and give auto scroll to that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always set the height and width of the enclosing `div` to get the scrolling effect and set the `display` property to `block` so that the scroll bar would come below the div (not below the table)

```
div.scroll{  
display:block;  
height:400px;  
overflow:auto;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/CLv7F/) it can help. Place the table inside the div then the scroll bar does not appear at the bottom of the table.

Use the max-height and max-width for your div like this

```
.simple{
overflow: auto;
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 180px;
}
```

Comment: This is like a workaround to the actual problem. The table data gets populated in real time and I have no control over the table data. By reducing the height and width, we are not actually making the scroll bars to float; but because of the decreased size, scroll bars 'appear' to be floating.

Comment: It works fine if the table data gets large and you can add the data in table and you must put the table in the div